# Book recommendation for network theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a mathematically rigorous book on Network theory covering topics like entropy, degree distribution, centrality, and regular, random, small-world and scale-free networks. I'm familiar with the basics of graph theory, at the level of Wilson. Could anyone suggest me some good books on network theory? Note:- A book suggested to me was Network Science by Ted. G. Lewis. However, I find the book riddled with serious mathematical errors, and it isn't rigorous enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excellent book on the matter is "Networks, Crowds, and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World".
A more brief one, but also a high quality work, is "Structure and Dynamics of Information in Networks" by David Kempe.

Cheers.