# Books on graph/network theory with linear algebra focus

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, book-recommendation, network

I am interested on getting feed back on books that are graph theory with focusing on linear algebra(have taken several courses on Linear Algebra)

I have gone through

1. Introductory Graph Theory by Gary Chartrand
2. Graph Theory and Complex Networks: An Introduction by Maarten van Steen
3. Graphs and Matrices by Ravindra B. Bapat

This is for personal learning to help me understand graph/network theory and how it interacts with geography. I have applications that do all the work around network theory but I want to actually learn it.

thanks for any feedback

Comment: Perhaps "Graphs and Matrices" by Bapat (ISBN-10: 1848829809)?

Comment: Moritz I had this book listed as one that I have already done

Comment: mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to the question

> [Textbook on Graph Theory using Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527842/textbook-on-graph-theory-using-linear-algebra)

except the stress on the networks so I could find

> [Book recommendation for network theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295379/book-recommendation-for-network-theory)

but I could not find a question on network theory and linear algebra, except that what is the difference between network theory and graph theory that considers graphs with terminals (vertices that cannot fail)?

Anyway, instead of focusing too much on the network theory because the term, network, used in so different meanings, I suggest the thread as a starter where some authors are suggesting books

> [First book on algebraic graph theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965640/first-book-on-algebraic-graph-theory)